# GTM consent mode Google analytics not tracking pageviews without consent

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

we have recently implemented cookies consent mode in Google tag manager. Pageviews in google analytics (both universal and GA 4) dropped to about 4 % of the original page views.

When I visit the web page **without giving any consent** some requests to google-analytics.com still appears in network tab. This tells me something is still tracked. No cookies are saved as expected.

Do you have a different experience? Should GA track pageviews anonymously even without consent or it this a correct behavior?  Why would analytics script send any requests if it not appears in GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that you see requests to Google Analytics. However in consent mode you should not see _ga cookies being set (or existing _ga cookies being used). That's basically what consent mode is, cookie-free tracking. You should also see a parameter `gcs=100` in the GA request to confirm that consent mode is indeed active.

However these requests are not surfaced in the reports (there would be no point, since without user identifier you cannot create sessions). Apparently they are being used for some sort of Machine Learning thing in the background, but I don't think this has much effect on the analytics part of GA (afaik this is more for Google Ads and GA audiences).

So yes, seeing requests in consent mode is normal (if this helps in any way with GDPR compliance etc. in entirely another matter). If you do not run campaigns and do not hope for an uplift via ML models applied to consent mode data, then you probably do not need to bother and can just disable the tags if no consent is given.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have more information or some source that can confirm these requests really shouldn't appear in the report? I have found this https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9976101 which confirms the requests should be send but it doesn't say anything about if you should see them in the report or not.

What do you mean by "without user identifier you cannot create sessions". I don't need to identify the user to be able to get sum of non unique pageviews. Or am I missing some GA fundamental principals?

Comment: You do not need to identify the user to be able to get the sum of non unique page views, but that is not what Google Analytics does (it aggregates requests into users and sessions). If you want the sum of unconnected page views in GA you should not use consent mode, but use disable the _ga cookie by setting storage to "none" (field in the configuration) and then pass in a freshly generated UUID as client_id (so that each request gets a new id; UUID is a a good format, since UUIDs do not repeat themselves). This will give non-unique page views, but will of course will cripple most reports.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to do that without much of a success. It seems like the GTM script and the consent mode breaks it, the storage option was ignored and it saved some cookies even without granted consent. It worked when I removed GTM script and inlined the GA script directly to the page. Of course I still need to use GTM and the consent mode for other scripts and don't want to have inline analytics script. But that is another issue. For now I will continue to use gtm consent mode and hope GA 4 will somehow solve this in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like GA4 actually does report something when linked to BigQuery for `analytics_storage=denied`: https://adswerve.com/blog/how-consent-mode-affects-the-way-google-analytics-records-data/

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have to set `ad_storage` and `analytics_storage` as `denied` by default in initialization code, like described in the documentation (in the example only *ad_storage* is denied, just add *analytics_storage* too): https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/consent#implementation_example

Comment: What if those values are not set?

Comment: Briefly (but the answer would be more elaborate) if you have active modeling you can see them in UI otherwise you lose them.